# can the thickbox height be increased on clicking a link in the thickbox?

Tags: jquery, thickbox

I have a thickbox that opens an url in an iframe. Initially when the thickbox loads, I have a div hidden. Later, through a click function of a link, the div is made visible. Now I have set the thickbox to the height of the initial iframe content, so that the white space is minimal. So when the hidden div is shown, the thickbox appears with scroll bars.

Can I increase the height of the thickbox dynamically on clicking the link? So that the scroll bars are avoided?

I have set the height of the thickbox manually in the thickbox.js file. I do not pass the height and width parameters.

```
 TB_WIDTH = (params['width']*1) + 30 || 980; //width need not change
 TB_HEIGHT = (params['height']*1) + 40 || 650;//need to change this to 1150 on clicking a link
```

**EDIT**

```
                     //Parent page
 <a href="thickbox.html" id="lightboxLink" class="thickbox"></a> //Opens the thickbox

                     //Thickbox content

 <div id="main-content">
           //Content

 </div>

 <div id="other-content" class="hidden"> //hidden div 
     // Div content
 </div>

<a id="more-info" href="#" >Show more information</a>

//js

$('#more-info').click(function() {   
     $('#other-content').show();
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your existing code please?

Comment: I was more referring to the html surrounding the link that's clicked to trigger the JS function that makes the div visible, as well as that function and any other relevant JS.

Answer (score 0):

The thickbox should have a containing div wrapped around the iframe. In the example I looked at, this div had an ID of `TB_Window`.  Assuming yours is the same, you could do something like the following in your jQuery code:

```
$('#more-info').click(function() {   
     $('#other-content').show();
     var thickboxHeight = parseInt($('#TB_Window').css('height'));
     var otherHeight = parseInt($('#other-content').css('height'));
     $('#TB_Window').css('height', (thickboxHeight + otherHeight).toString() + 'px');
});
```

Or if you just need to set it to 1150px (just saw that in your code comments) it's much simpler:

```
$('#more-info').click(function() {   
     $('#other-content').show();
     $('#TB_Window').css('height', '1150px');
});
```